# 2 constraint optimization (Lagrange multipliers)

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Determine the critical points of $x^3 + y^3 +z^3$, such that $x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 1$ and $x + y+ z = 0$ by hand.

Attempt at a solution: I seem to figure out $-1$ as the multiplier for $x+y+z=0$ but can't proceed as the equations seems duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3$, $u(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$ and $v(x,y,z)=x+y+z$. Then the critical points of $f$ restrict to $u(x,y,z)=0$ and $v(x,y,z)=0$ is  too the critical points of 
$$
F(x,y,z,\mu,\lambda)=f(x,y,z)+\mu u(x,y,z)+ \lambda v(x,y,z).
$$
The critical points of $F$ satisfies $\nabla F(x,y,z,\mu,\lambda )=0$.That is, 
$$
\begin{array}{lcrcr}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
(1)&\dfrac{\;\partial}{\partial {x}}F(x,y,z)&=&0\\
(2)&\dfrac{\;\partial}{\partial {y}}F(x,y,z)&=&0\\
(3)&\dfrac{\;\partial}{\partial {z}}F(x,y,z)&=&0\\
(4)&\dfrac{\;\partial}{\partial {\mu}}F(x,y,z)&=&0\\
(5)&\dfrac{\;\partial}{\partial {\lambda}}F(x,y,z)&=&0\\
\end{array}
\right.
&
\Longleftrightarrow
&
\left\{
\begin{array}{crcl}
(1)& 3x^2+2\mu x+\lambda&=&0\\
(2)& 3y^2+2\mu y+\lambda&=&0\\
(3)& 3z^2+2\mu z+\lambda&=&0\\
(4)& x^2+y^2+z^2&=&1\\
(5)& x+y+z&=&0\\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
$$
Note that
$$
(1)+(2)+(3) : 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2\mu(x+y+z)+3\lambda=0\implies \lambda=-1.\\
(1), \mbox{ and } \lambda=-1 \implies x=\frac{-2\mu\pm \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6}\\
(2), \mbox{ and } \lambda=-1 \implies y=\frac{-2\mu\pm \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6}\\
(3), \mbox{ and } \lambda=-1 \implies z=\frac{-2\mu\pm \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6}\\
$$
Cases
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& x & y & z & \mu \mbox{ in (5) }
\\\hline
Case 1 
& 
x=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
y=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
z=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
&
\mbox{ not existis  }
\\\hline
Case 2 
& 
x=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
y=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
z=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
&
\mbox{ existis  }
\\\hline
Case 3 
& 
x=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
y=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
z=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
&
\mbox{ existis  }
\\\hline
Case 4 
& 
x=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
y=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
z=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
&
\mbox{ existis  }
\\\hline
Case 5 
& 
x=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
y=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
z=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
&
\mbox{ existis  }
\\\hline
Case 6 
& 
x=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
y=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
z=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
&
\mbox{ existis  }
\\\hline
Case 7 
& 
x=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
y=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
z=\frac{-2\mu+ \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
&
\mbox{ existis  }
\\\hline
Case 8 
& 
x=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
y=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
& 
z=\frac{-2\mu- \sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6} 
&
\mbox{ not existis  }
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
For cases $2$ to $7$ we have in $(5) x+y+z=0$
\begin{align}
-\mu\pm \frac{\sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6}=0
\implies &
-\mu =\mp \frac{\sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6}
\\
\implies &
(-\mu )^2=\left(\mp \frac{\sqrt{4\mu^2+12}}{6}\right)^2
\\
\implies &
36\mu^2=|4\mu^2+12|
\\
\implies &
36\mu^2=4\mu^2+12
\\
\implies &
32\mu^2=12
\\
\implies 
&\mu^2=\frac{3}{8}
\\
\implies 
&\mu=\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}
\\
\implies 
&\mu=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}
=
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}
=
\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}
\\
\end{align}
The expression $\sqrt{4\mu^2+12}$ for $\mu=3/8$ is 
$$
\sqrt{4\mu^2+12}=\sqrt{27/2} =3\sqrt{3/2}=3\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}
$$
Then the expressions to $x$, $y$ and $z$, in case 2, for exemple, are
$$
\begin{array}{c}
x=\frac{1}{6}\left(-2\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}+ 3\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}  \right)
=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}
\\
y=\frac{1}{6}\left(-2\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}+ 3\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}  \right)
=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}
\\
z=\frac{1}{6}\left(-2\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}- 3\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}  \right)
=-2\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: You done it! I'm amazed!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use $$F(x,y,z,\alpha,\beta)=x^3+y^3+z^3+\alpha(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)+\beta(x+y+z)$$ and differentiate $F$ with respect to $x,y,z,\alpha,\beta$
we get
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=3x^2+2\alpha x+\beta=0$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=3y^2+2\alpha y+\beta=0$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=3z^2+2\alpha z+\beta=0$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \alpha}=x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \beta}=x+y+z=0$$
Have you solved this system?

Comment: ∂F/∂x + ∂F/∂y + ∂F/∂z = 3(x^2 + y^2 +z^2) +2α( x+y+z) +3β = 0
we get β= -1 but that's as far as i go